# unixODBC-qui-qt installation - cannot compile Qt program

Tags: unixodbc, rodbc

I am trying to setup unixODBC for Mac OSX Mountain Lion so that I can use RODBC to access to excel spreadsheet.

I did lots of research over various documentation and web sites and understand the following steps:

1. install unixODBC 2.3.1
2. install FreeTDS 0.91 (just want a free ODBC driver to test out)
3. specify the ODBC driver to be used. I have created a tds.driver.template and have installed in unixODBC successfully. see below:

   [FreeTDS] 
   Description     = v0.63 with protocol v8.0 
   Driver          = /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so

   $ sudo odbcinst -i -d -f tds.driver.template

   $ odbcinst -q -d 
   [FreeTDS]

And finally make a connection to a specific DSN. But when I try to configure unixODBC-gui-qt as below:

```
./configure --with-qt-dir-include=/usr/include --with-qt-dir-lib=/usr/lib --with-qt-dir-bin=/usr/bin
```

It gives the following errors:

```
configure: checking for Qt
yes (/usr/include)
yes (/usr/lib)
yes (/usr/bin)
checking for /usr/include/QtGui/QWizard... no
checking for /usr/include/QtGui/QMdiArea... no
configure: qt_dir_lib=/usr/lib
configure: LDFLAGS=
configure: X_LIBS= -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib
checking whether a simple Qt program compiles... no
configure: error: cannot compile a Qt program!
```

Before the installation above, I already installed autoconf, automake, libtool and the Qt library 4.8.4 for Mac OSX.

First question:  do I miss any step or mis-configure at some points?
I am learning R now but spending two days to configure ODBC on Mac i a bit out of my expectation. I just want to use the tools all from unixODBC including its driver manager and GUI tool to specify DSN. Should I go with emacs to edit odbc.ini instead?

Second question: after I specify the DSN, is it all that I can use RODBC to access to a Excel spreadsheet?  Now, it has the following error. And I am not sure if any step is necessary to configure RODBC to use unixODBC instead of iODBC.

```
> library(RODBC)
> conn.xls = odbcConnect ("~/Documents/R/R軟體應用統計方法/my notes/babies.xls")
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=~/Documents/R/R軟體應用統計方法/my notes/babies.xls") :
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code -83788248, message [iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded
```

Thanks very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same problems, I use OpenSuse 13.1 and Qt4.

In order to resolve this problem see the file config.log, probably the linker cannot find the QtAssistant.

As [98-Qt-assistant-under-linux](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/98-Qt-assistant-under-linux) this library was removed from Qt4.
You need to manually download it and install on system library path.

Luckily in OpenSuse this library is packaged with name libQtAssistantClient4, and you can install it using

```
zypper in libQtAssistantClient4
```

Also you need to create a symlink

```
cd /usr/lib64/
ln -s libQtAssistantClient.so.4 libQtAssistantClient.so
```

I hope this help to solve your problem